# Android json listview save data

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity, android-listview

I parse some data in Json format to android application from url, I created a clickable listview and now I want to create a shopping cart...
There are many item and when I click on each of them there are product name, price and availability, but there is not any unique ID to recognize them, All I want to do at this time it set quantity and use it later at the checkout page and send the data to the server.
So I created the EditText and Button in the productdetails layout but I have no idea how to save the value of EditText for the selected item and use it later at the checkout activity. Also I want when the user entered the quantity in the EditText and clicked on the back button it save that data on the memory so when after he clicked on the same item again the app show the selected quantity.... I have no idea how to do that.
is it even possible to do that ?! should I wrote new class and new code to be able to do that ?!

Here is the code of my second activity :

```
public class SingleListItem extends Activity{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.setContentView(R.layout.productdetails);

        TextView txtname = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.product_name);
        TextView txtprice = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.product_price);
        TextView txtfound = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.product_found);
        final TextView quantity1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewCurrentlyInCart);



        Intent intnt = getIntent();
        // getting attached intent data
        String selval = intnt.getStringExtra("selval");
        String selval1 = intnt.getStringExtra("selval1");
        String selval2 = intnt.getStringExtra("selval2");
        // displaying selected product name
        txtname.setText(selval);
        txtprice.setText(selval1);
        txtfound.setText(selval2);

           // Close the activity
              //  finish();
        Button   mButton;
        final EditText mEdit;

        mButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.ButtonAddToCart);
        mEdit   = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextQuantity);

        mButton.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener()
                {
                    public void onClick(View view)
                    {
                        Log.v("EditText", mEdit.getText().toString());

                    //    int quantity = Integer.valueOf(mEdit.getText().toString());
                        String quantity = mEdit.getText().toString();
                        quantity1.setText(quantity);
                    }
                });

    }

    }
```

Comment: You definitely need a unique ID to recognise each item. When you have that ID in the response, you can tag each view with that ID and use that tag to save value from the `EditText` of that very item and use it anywhere else.

Comment: the name are unique, also i can provide an ID for each product, but what next ? how can I do that ?